# I want php zip class extension to compress a directory , but without temp files

Tags: php, zip, compression

I want an extension to compress directory with all files and sub-dirs inside it, **but without creating a temp files**, i want the extrnsion name with a code for how to use it ?

i have an errors when the class making a temp files

Thank you ,

Comment: Why? What problem are you encountering related to temporary files?

Comment: What is the problem with the [ZipArchive](http://www.php.net/zip) class/package/extension? What packages/classes have you already tested which created temp files? What is the problem with these temp files?

Comment: @Programmer if you get an error creating a temp file, the more productive approach is probably to try and fix that problem. It's possible that all Zip libraries try to write into files in one way or another. What error message(s) are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You want http://pablotron.org/software/zipstream-php/. From the documentation:

```
1.  Create the zip stream:

    $zip = new ZipStream('example.zip');

2.  Add one or more files to the archive:

    # add first file
    $data = file_get_contents('some_file.gif');
    $zip->add_file('some_file.gif', $data);

    # add second file
    $data = file_get_contents('some_file.gif');
    $zip->add_file('another_file.png', $data);

3.  Finish the zip stream:

    $zip->finish();
```

I will warn you: if you're dealing with very large files the zip will break. it works well on small files, but not on 10s of megabytes.